# jQuery 1.8.0 1.8.1 1.8.2 - Why does $('%') raise an exception?

Tags: jquery

I thought if the selector is invalid it would return an empty set to maintain chainability but  in this case it raises an exception:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: %

Also:

```
$('aaa % bbb'); // raises exception.
```

But:

```
$('aaa % <a>bbbb</a>'); // does NOT raise an exception.
```

Can someone shed light on this?

It used to work in 1.7.2

Comment: The second one is interpreted as a chunk of HTML, so the `%` has no special meaning. The first one is interpreted as a selector, but since `%` isn't a selector, it breaks.

Comment: @Blender Should be posted as answer :-)

Comment: jquery's $() is getting stricter with each version, moving toward the goal of improving overall performance. `aaa % bbb` looks like a selector, but it doesn't work properly because it isn't a valid selector. If you want that to be interpreted as html, wrap it in an html tag.

Comment: The 1.8.2 way to guarantee it will work is to use `$($.parseHTML("aaa % bbb")).appendTo(target)` I remember reading somewhere that eventually $() will not accept complex html in favor of `$.parseHTML`